# How to print f-score, precison and recall using scikit learn in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I want to calculate and print many metrics (recall, f-score, accuracy) using sickit learn in python.
I am doing nlp, basicaly y_pred and y_test are list of words, I vectorise them with `pipe_vect.transform`, and i use sklearn.metrics to print metrics.

My code :

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.15, random_state=42)
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(x_train,y_train, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
x_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
x_valid = np.array(x_valid)
y_valid = np.array(y_valid)
y_test = np.array(y_test)
x_test = np.array(x_test) 
x_train = np.concatenate((x_train, x_valid))
 y_train = np.concatenate((y_train, y_valid))
    model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=int(clf_params['n_estimators']),
                                   max_features=clf_params['max_features'])
model.fit(pipe_vect.transform(x_train), y_train)
x_test_vect = pipe_vect.transform(x_test)
y_pred = model.predict_proba(x_test_vect)
 #y_pred.shape # (417,1)
y_pred = y_pred.flatten()
y_pred.shape # (417,)
print('y_pred',  y_pred)
print('y_pred dimension: ', y_pred.shape) #y_pred dimension:  (417,)
print('y_test dimension: ', y_test.shape) #y_test dimension:  (417,)
precision, recall, fscore, support = score(y_test, y_pred)
print('precision: {}'.format(precision))
print('recall: {}'.format(recall))
print('fscore: {}'.format(fscore))
print('support: {}'.format(support))
```

print :

```
y_pred dimension:  (417,)
y_test dimension:  (417,)
precision: [0. 0.]
recall: [0. 0.]
fscore: [0. 0.]
support: [  0. 417.]
```

I don't understand why my print are 0.

Comment: Irrelevant to the issue, but why exactly you split your `x_train` for a second time to `x_train` and `x_valid`, only to `concatenate` them a few lines below back to `x_train`? (And irrelevant to the issue it may be, but code here is supposed to be [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) among other things)

Comment: See sklearn.metrics htps://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#sklearn-metrics-metrics